# Python: Classes that use other classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have 2 files that work together using each other's classes.

I have

```
class Student:
    """A class to model a student with name, id and list of test grades"""
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        """initializes the name and id number; sets list of grades to []"""
        self.s_name = name
        self.ident = id
        self.tests=[]

    def getID(self):
        return self.ident

    def get_name(self):
        """ returns the student name"""
        return self.s_name
    def addtest(self,t):
        """adds a grade to the list of test grades """
        self.tests.append(t)
    def __str__(self):
        """returns the student name and the current list of grades"""
        return self.s_name + "  " + str(self.tests) + "  " 

    def comp_av(self):
        """returns the average of the current set of grades or 'no grades'
        if appropriate"""
        if len(self.tests) > 0:
            sum = 0.0
            for item in self.tests:
                sum = sum + item
            average = float(sum)/len(self.tests)
            return average
        else:
            return "no grades"
```

Which is completely done. I also have code that is from the teacher's point of view. The students are not just represented by their names but by an object of class `Student`.  Each Student object has their name and ID number, but also a list of test scores.  Right now Course has only the constructor and the `__str__` method.

```
from LabStudentClass import *

class Course:
    """ A class to model a course which contains a list of students"""
    def __init__(self,teacher):
        """Sets up a class to hold and update students"""
        self.students = []
        self.teacher = teacher

    def __str__(self):
        """ prints the course by listing each student in the class"""
        result = self.teacher+"'s Class\n"
        for s in self.students:
            name = s.get_name()
            result = result + name + '\n'

        return result

c = Course("Dr. Bradshaw")
#print c

def AddStudent(name, id):
    student1 = Student('Mary Comtpon', '3456')
    student2 = Student('Billy Jo', '2345')
    student3 = Student( 'Anne lou', '1090')

    print student1
    print student2
    print student3
```

My goal is to create a method `AddStudent`:  This method gets two parameters, a student name and an ID.  A new Student object is created and added to the course.

Add 3 students to your class and print out the class to test it.

However, the students aren't printing and I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: You're printing the students in a function named `AddStudent`; have you actually *called* that function somewhere? That would explain why you don't see the output you expect.

Comment: what is "the Create a method"?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your `Course` class:

```
def addStudent(self, name, id):
    student = new Student(name, id)
    self.students.append(student)
```

Then, replace the function you wrote at the bottom with the following:

```
c.addStudent('Mary Comtpon', '3456')
c.addStudent('Billy Jo', '2345')
c.addStudent('Anne lou', '1090')

print c
```